# Whats the hotkey for changing viewer rotation?

Tags: 3d-view

Right now when I MMB move it rotates turn-table style, whats the hotkey to free rotate around an object and return to turn-table?

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution to this, but it's a work around.

You can set an empty at the center of your focal target, and parent your camera to it.

To do that select the Camera 1st, then while holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key select your Empty.

Then on your keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent.

To get the turn table effect go into camera view <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, then select your empty and rotate it about the Z Axis.

Then use middle mouse as your trackball.

[image: Parented Camera To Empty View Rotation Demonstration]

Answer (score 2):

I found out I can roll with shift+numpad-4 and shift+numpad-6

Comment: Try these two as well: Alt+Ctrl+ScrollWheel & Alt+Shift+ScrollWheel

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make a hotkey to toggle the option, though figuring out how seems to involve bouncing through the python API documentation and blindly flailing about until something related to what you're reading about actually works.

The solution is: make a new keybind in the `3D View (Global)` category with type `wm.context_toggle_enum`, set the Context Attribute input to `user_preferences.inputs.view_rotate_method`, and set the values to `TRACKBALL` and `TURNTABLE`. It should look like this:

[image: above mentioned configuration bound to ctrl-q]

Though if you use my hotkey you'll want to remove the one for quitting on ctrl-q. IMO that might be a good idea anyway >.>.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, their is currently no keyboard shortcut. (Although someone could right an addon for that)

However you can, if you feel the need to use both rotation modes at once, just set the orbit-style to *Trackball* in the user preferences and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> to rotate around; turn table-style.